# How to make an animation of shrinking bitmap and get rid of the “shadow” around it by using StretchBlt in OnEraseBkgnd()? (MFC)

Tags: c++, mfc

I'd want to make an animation of shrinking bitmap using `StretchBlt` in `OnEraseBkgnd()`.

Here's my code:

```
BOOL CMainDlg::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC)
{
    double rat = 1;     //ratio
    double width, height, x, y, time=0;
    CBitmap Background;
    BITMAP bm;
    CDC dcMemory;

    Background.LoadBitmap(IDB_COVER);   //Load Bitmap
    Background.GetBitmap(&bm);      //Load Bitmap into handle

    dcMemory.CreateCompatibleDC(pDC);
    dcMemory.SelectObject(&Background);

    pDC->SetStretchBltMode(HALFTONE);

    while(time <= 300){
        width = 800 * rat;
        height = 600 * rat;
        x = (800 - width) / 2;
        y = (600 - height) / 2;
        pDC->StretchBlt((int)x, (int)y, (int)width, (int)height, &dcMemory, 0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, SRCCOPY);
        rat = easeOutExpo(time,1,-0.5,300);
        time+=5;
        Sleep(5);   //Delay 5 millisecond
    }

    return TRUE;
}

double CMainDlg::easeOutExpo(double e,double t,double u,double a){
    return (e==a)?t+u:u*(-pow(2,-10*e/a)+1)+t;
}
```

The problem is when the bitmap is shrinking, there's a “shadow” around the shrinking bitmap.

Like the image below:

[image: “shadow” around the shrinking bitmap]

How should I solve the “shadow problem?”

**EDIT:**

Below is ALL of my original code.

I'd want to show a WELCOME PICTURE and then get into the main program.

In the `OnEraseBkgnd()`, I want to shrink the WELCOME PICTURE from `ratio=1` to `ratio=9.5`. (800 is the original width of the bitmap `IDB_COVER` and 600 is the original height)

Here I use `AlphaBlend` instead of `StretchBlt`.

```
#include <afxwin.h> 
#include <math.h>
#include "resource.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "msimg32.lib")

#define AC_SRC_ALPHA                0x01


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// CMainDlg dialog
class CMainDlg : public CDialog
{
// Construction
public:
    CMainDlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL); // standard constructor

// Dialog Data
    enum { IDD = IDD_MAIN_DIALOG };
protected:
    virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
};



class CSplashDlg : public CDialog
{
public:
    CSplashDlg(){
        Create(IDD_LOADING);
    }

    CBitmap Background;
    BITMAP bm;
    CDC dcMemory;
    BLENDFUNCTION m_bf; 
    CRect rect;

    double rat;
    double width, height, x, y, time;

    CDC* cdc;


    virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
    afx_msg double easeOutExpo(double,double,double,double);
    afx_msg BOOL OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC);
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

CMainDlg::CMainDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialog(CMainDlg::IDD, pParent)
{
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CSplashDlg, CDialog)
    ON_WM_ERASEBKGND()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

BOOL CMainDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CClientDC dc(this);
    CSplashDlg Frame;

    Frame.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
    Sleep(1000);
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();

    return TRUE;
}

BOOL CSplashDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();

    SetWindowText(L"VB期末報告");
    MoveWindow(0, 0, 800, 600);
    CenterWindow();

    Background.LoadBitmap(IDB_COVER); //Load Bitmap
    Background.GetBitmap(&bm); //Load Bitmap into handle


    return TRUE;
}

BOOL CSplashDlg::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC)
{
    rat = 1;    //Original Resizing ratio
    time = 0;

    dcMemory.CreateCompatibleDC(pDC);
    CBitmap *pOldbmp = dcMemory.SelectObject(&Background);
    GetClientRect(rect);

    m_bf.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
    m_bf.BlendFlags = 0;
    m_bf.SourceConstantAlpha = 255;
    m_bf.AlphaFormat = AC_SRC_ALPHA;


    while(time <= 300)
    {

        width = 800 * rat;
        height = 600 * rat;
        x = (800 - width) / 2;
        y = (600 - height) / 2;


        AlphaBlend(pDC->GetSafeHdc(),(int)x,(int)y,(int)width,(int)height,dcMemory.GetSafeHdc(),0,0,bm.bmWidth,bm.bmHeight,m_bf);

        rat = easeOutExpo(time,1,-0.5,300);   //Ratio from 1 to 9.5
        time+=5;
        Sleep(5);
    }

    cdc = pDC;

    return TRUE;
}

double CSplashDlg::easeOutExpo(double e,double t,double u,double a){
    return (e==a)?t+u:u*(-pow(2,-10*e/a)+1)+t;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class MyApp : public CWinApp
{
public:
    BOOL InitInstance()
    {
        InitCommonControls();

        CMainDlg dlg;

        dlg.DoModal();

        return FALSE;
    }
} a_app;
```

**EDIT2:**

I forgot to say that the dialog border of `IDD_LOADING` is ***NONE***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is painting a smaller and smaller image over the original image. You have to repaint the background each time, and then paint the new smaller image. For example:

```
pDC->FillSolidRect(&rect, GetSysColor(COLOR_3DFACE));
pDC->StretchBlt(x, y, width, height, &dcMemory, 0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, SRCCOPY);
```

However, you have to use double-buffering to avoid flicker.

First, create a memory dc, similar to the one you created earlier (`buffer_dc`), and a memory bitmap (`buffer_bitmap`).

In each pass, use `FillSolidRect` to fill the background for `buffer_dc`. Paint the image over `buffer_dc`. Finally `BitBlt` everything to `pDC`:

```
BOOL CMainDlg::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC)
{
    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect(&rect);
    CDC buffer_dc;
    buffer_dc.CreateCompatibleDC(pDC);
    CBitmap buffer_bitmap;
    buffer_bitmap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(pDC, rect.Width(), rect.Height());
    CBitmap *buffer_oldbmp = buffer_dc.SelectObject(&buffer_bitmap);

    ...
    while(time <= 300)
    {
        ...
        buffer_dc.FillSolidRect(&rect, GetSysColor(COLOR_3DFACE));
        buffer_dc.StretchBlt((int)x, (int)y, (int)width, (int)height, &dcMemory, 0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, SRCCOPY);
        pDC->BitBlt(0, 0, rect.Width(), rect.Height(), &buffer_dc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

        Sleep(5);   
        ...
    }

    buffer_dc.SelectObject(buffer_oldbmp);
    return TRUE;
}
```

Running this code in `OnEraseBkgnd` is very inefficient. Simply change `OnEraseBkgnd` to return `TRUE`, then do the painting in `OnPaint`. Use `SetTimer` for the count down and call to `Invalidate`

---

Another method to make splash screen:

Create a window, resize the window, and paint on the window...

Use `dc.SetStretchBltMode(COLORONCOLOR)` instead of `HALFTONE` for improved performance.

---

Edit 3:

---

Note, `OnInitDialog` is used for initialization only. When you call `Invalidate` while still `OnInitDialog`, the message is ignored because the system is not finished processing the message for `WM_INITDIALOG`. You can instead create a timer, finish the initialization, and let the timer handle the painting and resizing. Example:

```
class CSpashDlg : public CDialog
{
public:
    CSpashDlg(CWnd *wnd = NULL):CDialog(IDD_SPLASH, wnd){}
private:
    CBitmap m_bitmap;
    int m_width, m_height;
    BOOL OnInitDialog()
    {
        CDialog::OnInitDialog();

        HBITMAP hbitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(0, L"test.bmp",
            IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
        if(!hbitmap)
        {
            AfxMessageBox(L"bitmap file not found\n");
            return TRUE;
        }

        m_bitmap.Attach(hbitmap);
        BITMAP bm;
        m_bitmap.GetBitmap(&bm);
        m_width = bm.bmWidth;
        m_height = bm.bmHeight;

        SetWindowPos(0, 100, 100, m_width, m_height, SWP_NOREDRAW);

        SetTimer(1, 1, 0);

        return TRUE;
    }

    void OnTimer(UINT_PTR timer)
    {
        if(timer != 1)
            return;
        CRect rc;
        GetWindowRect(&rc);
        if(rc.Width() < 10 || rc.Height() < 10)
        {
            KillTimer(1);
            PostMessage(WM_COMMAND, IDCANCEL);
            return;
        }

        rc.InflateRect(-1, -1);
        SetWindowPos(0, rc.left, rc.top, rc.Width(), rc.Height(), SWP_NOREDRAW);
        Invalidate(FALSE);
    }

    void OnPaint()
    {
        CPaintDC dc(this);
        CRect rc;
        GetClientRect(&rc);

        CDC memdc;
        memdc.CreateCompatibleDC(0);
        memdc.SelectObject(&m_bitmap);

        dc.SetStretchBltMode(COLORONCOLOR);
        dc.StretchBlt(0, 0, rc.Width(), rc.Height(), 
            &memdc, 0, 0, m_width, m_height, SRCCOPY);
    }

    BOOL OnEraseBkgnd(CDC*)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CSpashDlg, CDialog)
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_ERASEBKGND()
    ON_WM_TIMER()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

class MyApp : public CWinApp
{
public:
    BOOL InitInstance()
    {
        CWinApp::InitInstance();

        CSpashDlg splash;
        splash.DoModal();

        CDialog dlg(IDD_DIALOG1);
        dlg.DoModal();
        return FALSE;
    }
} a_app;
```

Comment: Thanks. But I have another background image under the bitmap. That means I can't use `FillSolidRect` to fill the “shadow”. So is there any way to recall `OnEraseBkgnd()`? Or any other way to solve this problem? By the way, the flickering problem is still existing. I don't know where the problem is...

Comment: Where are you painting the background image? Show all the painting code in `OnPaint`, `OnEraseBkgnd`...

Comment: Actually, what I said is not a "real" background image. I just want to express that the background is not monochrome. 

And my original thought is to show the bitmap on the "screen" directly. (not on the dialog) So the "background (outside of the dialog)" isn't a pure color.

Comment: See the edit for how to handle `Invalidate`. The dialog can invalidate itself, but it cannot do that from `OnInitDialog` as you attempted to do in another topic.